# mouseenter and document click blinks first li element always

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just created a ribbon style menu the problem is in FireFox and Google Chrome browsers when you mouseenter and document click the first element in the list always blinks I dont have this problem in IE could someone check out my page and view the source and have a look at my jquery code and see if you can find whats causing this small glitch - the page is [here](http://shopnbuy.vacau.com/menu.php)

It must be todo with my mouseenter function I pass in this selected_slide(this)

mouseenter:

```
function select_slide(element) {
    if($(element).hasClass('.nav_divider_before')) return 
    $('.nav_browse_ul li')..removeClass('active');      
    $(element).addClass('active');      

    if($(element).attr('data-id') != null) {
        var current_content = $('#' + $(element).attr('data-id'));

        selected_slide = current_content;               
        $('.ribbon_slides').show();
        rotate_ribbon_slides(element);      

        if(isAnimating) return;

            if(!isOpen) {
                isAnimating = true;
                $('.ribbon_slides').animate({'width': '+=' + (current_content.width() + 20).toString() })
                $('.ribbon_panel').animate({'width': '+=' + (current_content.width() - 14).toString()}, function(){ 
                    isOpen = true;
                    isAnimating = false;
                })              
            }

        }

    }
```

document click

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
        /**/
        if(!$(e.target).closest('.ribbonmenu').length) {
            if($('.nav_browse_ul li').hasClass('active')) {
                $('.nav_browse_ul li').removeClass('active');   
            }
            $('.ribbon_slides').animate({'width': '-=' + ($(selected_slide).width() + 20).toString()});
            $('.ribbon_panel').animate({'width': '-=' + $(selected_slide).width()}, function() {
                $('.nav_browse_ul li.nav_divider_before').css('margin-right', '0px');
                $('.ribbon_slides').hide();                     
            });

            isOpen = false;
        }

    })
```

Comment: would be nice to know why I was down voted for asking a asking about a problem Im having

Comment: +1 for nice design but it would be easy for us to help if you provide us some code as well (relevant)

Comment: It seems to be on the mouseenter and document click functions that cause the problem if i take out the function in document.click I don't get the problem but I don't understand what causes it

Comment: @KDM Add the related code here...

Comment: updated my post with related code